# JTextArea Indentation settings

Tags: java, swing, indentation, jtextarea

I am trying to find out how to only move 4 spaces forward in JTextArea, when pressing the 'tab' key on the keyboard. Currently it moves forward 8 spaces.

I've done some reading on Styles in Java and came across setLeftIndent() however this isn't what I need. I have thought about using a key listener so anytime 'tab' is pressed in JTextArea, it only moves forwards by 4 spaces (keybindings).

I would appreciate any advices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setTabSize(...)` method of JTextArea:

```
textArea.setTabSize( 4);
```